# Perl: function returns reference or copy?

Tags: perl, function, return-type

Im a newbie in perl. So the question might sound something naive.

I have two following functions

```
#This function will return the reference of the array
sub getFruits1
{
    my @fruits = ('apple', 'orange', 'grape');
    return \@fruits;
}
```

But in the following case?

```
#How it returns?
sub getFruits2
{
    my @fruits = ('apple', 'orange', 'grape');
    return @fruits;
}
```

Will `getFruits2` return a reference and a new copy of that array will be created?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `getFruits2` subroutine returns a *list*, which can be assigned to a new array like this

```
my @newfruits = getFruits2();
```

And yes, it will produce a copy of the data in the array

Comment: Great!! your answer taught me the difference between array and list also. I never thought of this earlier. After a quick googling I also got this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6024268/1160106. Thanks.

Comment: See also [What is the difference between a list and an array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array?) in perlfaq4

Answer (score 4):

`getFruits1` will return a reference to an array. The `\` creates a reference.

`getFruits2` will return a list of the values in `@fruits`. It won't return a reference. You'll only get a copy of the array if you assign the return value to an array.

Answer (score 1):

`getFruits1` returns a reference.No new array is created.

`getFruits2` returns a list

An example of Perl referencing

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use strict;

my @array = ('a','b','c');
printf("[%s]\n",join('',@array));
my $ref=\@array;
${@{$ref}}[0]='x'; # Modifies @array using reference
printf("[%s]\n",join('',@array));
```

Comment: `getFruits2` really doesn't return an array. As the other answers note, it's a list.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that can be returned by a sub is a list of scalars. Arrays can't be returned.

```
\@fruits
```

evaluates to a reference, so

```
return \@fruits;
```

returns a reference. In list context,

```
@fruits
```

evaluates to a list of the elements of `@fruits`, so

```
return @fruits;
```

returns a list of the elements of `@fruits` if the sub is evaluated in list context.