# Perl: Anonymous Multi-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, reference

**NOTE: See the end of this post for final explanation.**

This is probably a very basic question, but I'm still trying to master a few of the fundamentals regarding references in Perl, and came across something in the perldsc page that I'd like to confirm.  The following code is in the Generating Array of Arrays section:

```
while ( <> ) {
   push @AoA, [ split ];
}
```

Obviously, the `<>` operation in the `while` loop reads one line of input in at a time.  I am assuming at this point that line is then put into an anonymous array via the `[ ]` brackets, we'll call this `@zero`. Then the split command places everything in a given line separated by whitespace within the array (e.g., the first word is assigned to `$zero[0]`, the second to `$zero[1]` and so on). The scalar reference of `@zero` is then pushed onto `@AoA`.

The next line of input is passed via the `<>` operator and gets assigned to a completely new anonymous array (e.g. `@one`), and its scalar reference is pushed onto `@AoA`.

Once `@AoA` is populated, I could then access its contents with a nested `foreach` loop; the first iterating through the "rows" (e.g. `for $row (@AoA)`), and a second, inner loop, `foreach` to access the columns of that particular row.

The latter (accessing said "columns" would be done by `dereferencing` (e.g., `for $column (@$row)`) the particular `$row` being read by the previous, "outer" `foreach` loop.
Is my understanding correct?  I'm assuming you could still access any element of the @AoA just as you would if it were assigned vs. being anonymous? That is `$element = $AoA[8][1];` .

I'm want to verify my thought process here. Is the automatic declaration of a unique, anonymous array each time through the loop part of the `autovivication` in Perl? I guess that is what is throwing me off a bit. Thanks.

**EDIT**: Based on the comments below my understanding regarding the anonymous array is still unclear, so I want to take a shot at one more description to see if it meets everyone's understanding.

Starting with the `push @AoA, [split];` statement, split takes in the line from $_ and returns a **list** parsed by whitepace.  That **list** is captured by `[ ]`, which then returns an array reference.  That array reference (created by `[ ]`) is then pushed onto @AoA.  Is this accurate re: `[ ]`? The next step (dereferencing / use of @AoA) was covered very well by @krico below.

**FINAL ANSWER/EXPLANATION**: Based on all of the comments / feedback here, some further research on my part, and testing it seems my understanding was correct.  I'll break it down here, so others can easily reference it later.  See @krico's response below for a more explicit code representation that follows the steps outlined here.

```
while ( <> ) {
    push @AoA, [ split ];
}
```

1. One line of input is passed at a time to the `<>` operator
2. The `split` function takes that line in via `$_` and parses it based on whitespace (the default).
3. `split` then returns a LIST.
4. The `[ ]` is an anonymous array that provides the perl data structure for the List passed by `split`.
5. The `push @AoA` pushes the reference to the anonymous array onto its queue as element `$AoA[0]` (the second anonymous array reference will be put into $AoA[1](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), etc...).
6. This continues through the entire input file.  Once completed, `@AoA` is a 2D array, holding reference values (scalar values) to each of the previously generated anonymous arrays.
7. From this point `@AoA` can be dereferenced appropriately to work with the underlying/reference elements taken in from the input file.  The default dereferencing technique is CIRCUMFIX (see perlfef below); however as of 5.19 a new method of dereferencing is available and will be released in 5.20, POSTFIX.  Articles are linked below.

*References*: [Perl References Documentation,](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) [Perl References Tutorial,](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) [Perl References Question noted by @Eli Hubert,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023821/perl-array-vs-list) [Mike Friedman's blog post about differences between arrays and lists,](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl) [Upcoming Postfix dereferencing in Perl, and](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/perl-5.19.5/pod/perlref.pod#Postfix_Dereference_Syntax) [Postfix dereferencing Article](http://perltricks.com/article/68/2014/2/13/Cool-new-Perl-feature-postfix-dereferencing)

Comment: Did you try what you've explained? If so, how did your output differ from what you were expecting?

Comment: @FlyingFrog Yes, I've gotten the results as I've described them.  I didn't really have an expectation up front.  It works, I just want to understand "why" it works.

Comment: `[ ITEMS ]` creates a new anonymous array and returns a reference to that array. You might find [perl reference tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Making-References) or [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023821/perl-array-vs-list)  helpful.

Comment: I wonder: Wouldn't use of the Perl debugger and `x @AoA` inside explain it all? The Perl debugger is great to examine your data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same code a little more readeable and you should understand it.

```
my $line;
while ( $line = <STDIN> ) {
   my @parts = split $line;
   my $partsRef = \@parts;
   push @AoA, $partsRef;
}
```

Now, if you wanted to print the 2nd part of the 5th line you could say.

```
my $ref = @AoA[4];
my @parts = @$ref;
print $parts[1];
```

Get it?

Comment: Yes, I do.  Thanks for breaking that part down.  I'm 90% there.  Based on some of the other comments I really want to capture the use of `[ ]` and the anonymous array, that's mainly what caused my confusion in the first place. I've edited the ending to my question to include my understanding thus far. Does that seem correct?

Comment: added explanation the end of my question based on your input.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is what is going on:

1. The <> will put the line into the default variable $_
2. The split function will read $_ and return an array
3. The [ ] brackets will return a scalar, in it there will be a reference to that array
4. That reference is then pushed into the @AoA array

When you do $AoA[8][2] you are implicitly dereferencing the scalar. It's the same as $AoA[8]->[2].

Comment: `[]` do not return a reference to *that* array, but to a newly created array with the same contents.

Comment: Nit: `split` returns a list, not an array.

Comment: @Kenosis @choroba Based on some of the comments here I really want to capture the use of `[ ]` as the anonymous array, that's mainly what caused my confusion in the first place. I've edited the ending to my original question to include my understanding thus far. Does this match what you were driving toward? Thanks