# Array vs. list data type?

Tags: raku

I know this has already been asked [for Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023821/perl-array-vs-list).
Does Raku make the same distinction between arrays and lists?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR** It makes a distinction, but not exactly the same one. In fact, it's very different in detail.

## Informal "list" and "array" concepts

There's the general *informal* concept of a "list" (with a lowercase 'l') which is the notion of one thing, then another, then another.

There are variants of this general notion: lists of arguments (captures), lists of parameters (signatures), lists of values, etc.

At this informal level the words "list" and "array" are largely interchangeable though "list" tends to emphasize immutability, "array" mutability.

## Formal types: `Positional`, `Iterable`, `List`, `Array`, `Seq`, etc.

More formally, listy things are typically types that ["do"](https://docs.raku.org/routine/does#%28Typesystem%29_trait_does)  listy [roles](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/role). The two main listy roles are the [`Positional`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Positional) and [`Iterable`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Iterable).

There is a [`List`](https://docs.raku.org/type/List) (capital 'L') type which [`does`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/does#%28Typesystem%29_trait_does) the `Positional` and `Iterable` roles. There is also an [`Array`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Array) type which is a sub-class of `List`. And there are native arrays which also do the `Positional` and `Iterable` roles but are [`array`](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativetypes#index-entry-native_array)s, not `Array`s nor `List`s:

```
my int @array;
say @array ~~ Array; # False
say @array ~~ array; # True
```

The behavioral differences between `List`s and arrays (either `Array`s or `array`s) relate to mutability. A `List` can easily be constructed so that it is guaranteed immutable. In contrast an array can never be intrinsically guaranteed immutable (though of course code can be written to not mutate it after construction). More specifically:

- **Adding or subtracting elements.** A `List`'s length cannot be changed after its construction. Methods such as `.push` will fail on a `List`. In contrast an array only has a fixed length if it's declared as having a fixed length at construction time.
- **Assigning and/or binding to elements.** A `List` element is never rebindable, and is only assignable if it's bound to an [lvalue](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#lvalue) at construction time. In contrast an `Array` element is always rebindable (I'm ignoring the NYI `::=`), and is only *not* assignable when it's bound to an immutable value.

There are several other important listy types, for example:

- A [`Seq`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Seq) is "An iterable, lazy sequence of values".
- A [`Capture`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Capture) is used for various purposes, most notably for containing argument lists and as the parent type of the regex/grammar `Match` class.

The "official" docs at [doc.raku.org](https://docs.raku.org/) has a [Lists, Sequences, and Arrays](https://docs.raku.org/language/list) page that should be helpful.

Comment: > and an arrays elements are always assignable using the = assignment operator.

This is not strictly true: you can bind an array element to an immutable value, after which you can **not** assign to it anymore because that element no longer is bound to a container: `my @a = ^10; @a[3] := 42; @a[3] = 666; # Cannot assign to an immutable value`

Comment: Thx for your edit and correction which I've incorporated. :)

Comment: "or not depending on whether they are bound to a Scalar or not." Perhaps better as: "if they're bound to a container, rather than an immutable value".

Comment: I'd really appreciate a go-to definitive reference for the difference between `.list` and `.List` method calls. Or should I post that question?

Comment: @jubilatious1 I'll write comments after this one, at least one for `.List`, and one for `.list`. Then we can discuss further here or you can post one or more questions.

Comment: `.List`. There is a convention that any named type (eg `Int` or `Date`) can have a type converter/creator named after it. `.List` is one of these type converters. `.List` *should* follow their example, in which, if the invocant does *not* already match the type then calling the type converter on it tries to create a new object of that type from the invocant, but if the invocant *already* matches then the converter is a "no op". Unfortunately [things got complicated](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2881).

Comment: `.list`. There is no named type `list`, just the concept of "an ordered list of values". So it's conceptually close, but, well, conceptual, not concrete. That said, in most cases it does the same thing, but, as discussed by niner in the comment following the one I just linked in my previous comment, `.List` coerces an `Array` to a `List`, whereas `.list` leaves it as an `Array`.

Answer (score 7):

Let me just add that in Perl, a list an ephemeral thing; in Raku it's a [regular type](https://docs.raku.org/type/List), and a comma-separated list of literals produces one:

```
$ raku -e 'say (1, 2, 3).^name'
List
```

Arrays also support the `push`, `pop`, `shift`, `unshift` and `splice` methods that Lists do not have.