# Result type of hyperoperators in Raku

Tags: raku

I am curious what rule determines the type of an expression including a hyperoperator. Let us consider these four kinds of Positionals:

```
my $ca = [1, 2];   # containerized array  $[1, 2]
my $ua := [1, 2];  # uncontanerized array [1, 2]
my $cl = (1, 2);   # containerized list   $(1, 2)
my $ul := (1, 2);  # uncontainerized list (1, 2)
```

I have observed that evaluating `x «+» y`, where `x` and `y` are taken from the above, results in an object of `x`'s kind (cont./uncont.; array/list), e.g. `$cl «+» $ua` is `$(2, 4)`.

However, the expression `0 «+» y` is an object of `y`'s kind, even though the docs claim that the left-hand side is converted to a list first. So `1 «+» $ua` is `[1, 2]`, while I would expect it to be `(1, 2)`.

What is the actual rule for the result type of a hyperoperator application?

Comment: It's rather "itemized", not containerized. They all containerized since they're using a sigilled variable.

Comment: @jjmerelo using a sigilled variable does **not** guarantee containerization.

Comment: "the docs claim that the left-hand side is converted to a list first" Do you mean "Single elements are turned to a list"?

Comment: Fwiw, there's a difference between a "list" and a `List` as outlined in the **Informal "list" and "array" concepts** section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49580888/1077672).

Comment: I think the core code is [this module](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core.c/Hyper.pm6). The comments look succinct and organized for whoever wrote them (Liz?) but it's far beyond my paygrade to figure out what's going on. I see lots of variations depending on the types of the LHS and RHS, use of `«+»` vs `»+«`, and so on. Perhaps [this code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/10c3dbb940290c67af33dfc617b2f8ce6a21df28/src/core.c/Hyper.pm6#L342-L363) and/or [this code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core.c/Hyper.pm6) is the key code? @ElizabethMattijsen?